# Is there a way to tag a post/question so that you get notifications when someone answers it?

Tags: discussion, questions, spam-detection

So I read a question and thought: 'what a smart question, I want a good answer to this question too'. So by commenting or answering I would get notifications, but I'd rather not spam that good question with comments if I don't have a good one or answering when I don't have an answer.

If there is a button saying 'follow this post', where is it? And if not could that be created? By getting a notification that a question you are interested has been answered, would be more handy than trying to remember the question and searching afterwards.

Comment: You can add it to favorites by clicking the star below the vote buttons.

Comment: Can you then unfavorite it after it has been answered and I'm pleased with the answer?

Comment: Click on the same star to achieve that.

Comment: Great, this seems to be duplicate, sorry for not finding this feature on my own. Should I delete this post?